# Pressure sensing controller using Stress Ball

Tags: motor, piezoelectricity, mobile-robot

I am thinking of a project proposal for my robotics course and we are required to make one that has a potential application on physical therapy or medical fields. One thing that came across my mind is a motorized wheelchair that moves when a stress ball control is squeezed by the user. As an electronics novice, I wonder if I could integrate a sensor circuit with a rubber ball so that when it is pressed, perhaps by a stroke patient, it triggers some driver circuit. is this possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. You can measure the squeezing force for example with an force sensitive resistor (FSR sensor) (see [Adafruit example](https://learn.adafruit.com/force-sensitive-resistor-fsr/overview)) or even built your own (fabric) pressure sensor (see [www.kobakant.at](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?cat=26)). All you need is a microcontroller with an ADC. For example every Arduino board has this capability. In addition you can use a motor shield/board or built your own circuit to control the motor system.